# Using Excel 2016, Getting errors using left function nested in a date value function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've imported data from Facebook. All I'm trying to do is get the Date Value function to work.  I have the one column that has the date as text "12/21/16" and a new column that I'm trying to get to format correctly as a date for a pivot table I'm creating.

I have the following =DATEVALUE(LEFT([@Date],10)) in a new column where [@Date] is the original date column.

Not sure what's creating this issue.  When i only use the left function, it gives me the correct number "42725" but it won't convert to an actual date.

Comment: Even when formatting the cell to be "Short Date" (or "Long Date"), it shows the `42725` number?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to explicitly force the value to a text result used in the DATEVALUE function. BUT you also need to set the cell format to display as a date

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(LEFT([@DATE],10),"MM/dd/YYY"))
```

[image]